# MS EXCEL FORMULA: Search Text within ROW and Return Value

Tags: excel, search, row

I would like to use a MS Excel Formula (Not Macros or VB), to independently search against each individual Row for matching Keywords and return the value in its respective cell.  See Sample Below

[image]

[image]

I would like for the MS Excel formula in practice to Search, Index and Match each discovered keyword data found in Rows versus Columns and output in cell (ultimately to capture and re-categorize text).

OUTPUT RESULTS:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried vlookup?

Comment: HLOOKUP Using wild cards will do it `=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(I$2 & "*",$A2:$G2,1,FALSE),"")` In I3, then copy over and down.

Comment: Scott, Thank you so very much, after more than 6 hours in my own attempt to solve the long awaited mystery, your formula works absolutely PERFECT.  Again, thank you... thank you....